# media queries css syntax error, shows in sublime text

Tags: css, media-queries

this is not sublime problem, my code

```
@media(min-width:801px){
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 370px;
}
```

shows in sublime the margin is in white color.. then I test in my browser, and as expected, the css doesn't apply.. the syntax above should be fine.. what is this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a selector within the media query, e.g.

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
    body {
        margin: 0 auto; 
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7MVx/2/

Answer (score 2):

You aren't applying those margins to any elements. A media query wraps around regular CSS selectors like so:

```css
@media (min-width:801px) {
    .myClass {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 370px;
    }
}
```

Refer to [MDN's CSS media queries page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-widht: 510px) {
.nav__ul {
    display: none;
}
```

}

Same problem, trying to apply this code, the ""max-widht doesn't appear as a posible property and stays in white. It doesnt. I have to copy the code from the web to make it work.

Comment: Please edit the question and place code in `code` blocks, your `}` is currently outside the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

you can define in scss this way,
for example,

```
body{
 @media(min-width:801px){
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 370px;

 }
}
```